# created buttons with user input, how to store them for the next time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a html page, where the user can create a button via javascript/jquery, which will appear on the html page after adding it. 
So my question is, how it is possible that the button will be there also if I am closing an opening the page again?

I hope my question is clear, I can also post my code if it is necessary! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear and you will need to post a [mcve] in it

Comment: You have to store the data *somewhere* to track that they've added the button, be it a database, text file, or even session/cookie. Consider doing some research, this question as it stands is too broad.

Comment: Create the button on page load .. then whenever u load the page that javascript code will be executed and button will be created ... Or you can use coockies ..

Comment: As it stands, Stack Snippets can't use localstorage or cookies. :( This will make it harder to give you a good example.... I guess I'll have to use JSFiddle.

Comment: If you are not storing this information on server side, and you just need store it for temporary purpose, you can use Local Storage of HTML 5

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use some server side code to do this.
You cannot rely on cookies since they will be gone sooner or later.
PHP with MySQL to store the information you need seems like the easiest approach for some simple user database interaction.
There's not much to work with here hope you find this response helpful and guiding you the right direction.

Comment: Cookies aren't even close to being deprecated :/

Comment: Not talking about deprecation. People tend to clear history and cached data a lot you know.

Comment: Oh so naive of me. Persistent would've been a better suited word though. P.S. I am not one of the down-voters. However, your answer does make sense so you have my up-vote :)